# Force input to fit font

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

My placeholder text is being clipped inside the input.  It works fine with certain fonts, eg. sans serif, but not with the font, Futura, I'm currently using.  How can I fit the input field properly around the text.

I'm seeing this,
[image]

but want the 'Search' to appear unclipped.

Input:

```
<input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Search...">
```

Css:

```
.search-input {
  display: block;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: Futura;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding: 0 4px 0 3px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Specs: Google Chrome 87.0.4280.88 on Ubuntu

Comment: you have an error, css comments are only `/*  your comment */`

Comment: I'm on chrome (linux), ill test it on firefox

Comment: yea, it is installed as woff2, good call though, it actually looks ok in firefox, so I guess it is one of the webkit things?

Comment: i have done that as well, the font works fine in other places, it is just in this input

Comment: it is available here: https://en.bestfonts.pro/font/futura-lt with a demo.html, I also have it installed locally, not sure if that is required to work in chrome

Comment: did you try `.search-input::-webkit-input-placeholder  {...` ?

Comment: thanks, I just did, but it seems to produce the same results

Comment: @MisterJojo yes! using `::-webkit-input-placeholder { line-height: 200%; }` did the trick. thanks alot, leave as answer if you want (`line-height` alone in `.search-input` wasn't enough)

Comment: it may well be, I have no way to test though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution seems to be:

```
.search-input::-webkit-input-placeholder  {
  line-height: 200%;
  /*  .... or more */
}
```